# Why the program blocks by the channel in the select?

Tags: go, select, channel

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct{
    exit chan bool
}

func (a *A) f(){
    select{
        //the routine process

        //quit
        case <- a.exit:

                fmt.Println("-----over-----")
                a.exit <- true
                fmt.Println("+++++over++++++")              
        }
}

func main() {

    a := A{}
    
    go a.f()
    a.exit = make(chan bool)
    
    a.exit <- true
}
```

I'd like to run muti goroutines,and I want let the main func to notice other goroutine to quit.
here is my code,but the program block in the select,the program only output "-----over-----",without "+++++over++++++",what's wrong with the code?Grateful for your help.

Comment: It will be fine if I change "a.exit = make(chan bool)" to "a.exit = make(chan bool,1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program blocks because that is what you have written, consider this order of operations:

1. `main` goroutine starts `a.f` goroutine.
2. `a.f` blocks trying to read from the nil channel `a.exit`.
3. `main` sets `a.exit` to be an unbuffered channel, `a.f` is now blocked reading from the new channel, this is allowed.
4. `main` writes a value into `a.exit` and `a.f` reads the value from `a.exit`, this synchronises the goroutines, nether are blocked now.
5. `a.f` now blocks trying to write into the unbuffered `a.exit`, this will never unblock because nobody will ever try to read from the channel again.
6. `main` now exits and causes all other goroutines to exit, this might happen before step 5.

So the reasons your program never outputs `+++++over++++++` are:

- Your `a.f` goroutine blocks at `a.exit <- true` because no other goroutine will read this value from the channel.
- Your `main` goroutine will probably exit and terminate the entire program before `a.f` can finish working.

I think you are asking how to make main exit after the goroutine is finished, this is the most simple example of that:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    exit chan struct{}
}

func (a *A) f() {
    defer close(a.exit) // Close the chanel after f() finishes, closed channels yield the zero-value so <-a.exit will unblock

    fmt.Println("+++++over++++++")
}

func main() {
    a := A{}
    go a.f()
    a.exit = make(chan struct{})

    <-a.exit
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.I see what's wrong with the code,there is actually some difference between unbuffered channel and channel with size 1. And in my program, I write in this way because I want to run many a.f(),so I want if a.f() quites,it still send the a.exit channel some information to notice other a.f() to quit(), so if I still want to use unbuffered channel,I probably need add a read of channel in the main func.Thanks for your help,I think I understand why it's wrong,and what can I do in my code.